# Strings in rows in R

Tags: r

I have a file and I made a function in R which accepts a string like 
110110110110110.

Now, the input file that has 1000's of rows and each row has these numbers in subsequent columns.

Example:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10  V11  V12  V13  V14  V15

1   1   1   0    1   1   0   1   1   0    1    1    0    1     1 

2   0   1   0    1   0   1   0   1   0    1    0    1    0     1

3

4

5 

6
```

Like this, I have thousand's of rows. The column V1 is the row number and V2-V28 contains either 1 or 0. Now, I want to apply the function to every row of my input file such that it the numbers in columns from V2-V28 forms the input string. I know how to do it if I had simple strings in rows in a file, but how to do it with columns?

Thanks.

Edit: The function that I have written accepts a string as input such as "110110110". However, what I have is a sequence of 1's and 0's in different columns (V2-V28) in each row.

Comment: Is this what you want: `data.frame(new.df = (do.call(paste0, df[,2:ncol(df)])))`  Maybe not since this is for rows.

Comment: Maybe this? `df2 <- data.frame(t(df));  data.frame(new.df = (do.call(paste0, df2)))`

Comment: This will take the transpose of the given data frame. I don't want that. I Want the numbers in columns 1 to 29 to be treated as a single string.

Comment: Is the code in my first comment okay?

Comment: No, your first comment narrows down the data frame to only variable.

Comment: Consider adding the exact result you want to your post.

Comment: What I want is that the numbers in the columns from V2-V28 should in every row form a string which I can further pass to my function because my function that I have written accepts a string as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
df    <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,0,0,0,1), V2= c(0,1,0,1,0), V3=c(0,0,0,0,0), V4=c(1,1,1,1,1))
input <- do.call(cbind, df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

Now you can use apply with margin 1 for rows, to pass it to the specified function:

```
apply(input, 1, do.something.with.vector)
```

Edit: To convert to string and remove the commata etc use it like this

```
apply(input, 1, function(x) print(gsub(", ","",toString(x))))
```

You can exchange "print" to your "do.something.with.vector" function.

Comment: What have you passed in the data.frame command? Will I have to do it for every column? And why are you combining, (1,0,0,0,1)?

Comment: The first line is an example for a data.frame. If you exchange the "print" command from my (edited) answer it will pass all strings "010010" to it. The strings are all columns 2-ncols(df) concatenated, with "," and spaces removed.

Comment: I just realised, Mark Millers code already did this. And much more elegantly. Shame on me. ;)

Comment: The command that you wrote, input <- do.call(......). This command effectively creates a matrix. What I want is that the numbers in the columns from V2-V28 should in every row form a string which I can further pass to my function.

Comment: look at the "apply". The "input" variable is just a substep. Edit: And don't look at the return value of "apply", look at what "print" does. Print is my "dummy" function, which can be replaced by yours.

Comment: What does it produce? Whats the difference to what you want it to produce? Help us to help you, please.

Comment: Yup. I got it. Thanks. I was getting confused between the intermediate file that was being made. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: is it possible that I can somehow write the value in the first column as well in the output file? That is, I want that if output of the function after passing in the string in row 10 is 110, then the output file should display, 10 110, i.e. row number as well?

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that the numbers in the columns from V2-V28 should in every row form a string which I can further pass to my function.

You can use the function paste with argument collapse = "". For example, given a sample matrix "m":

```
m <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

You can apply the function "paste" by rows for the desired columns (e.g second to fourth columns):

```
apply(m[,2:4], 1, paste, collapse = "")
[1] "5913"  "61014" "71115" "81216"
```